# MySQL Server start permission denied

Tags: mysql, macos

I am a a newbie to database programming and I want to try out MySQL.
I just installed MySQL from the official website, I am running mac 10.8.2.
Anyways, whenever I try to run a simple command like `$>mysql.server start`
it says *Permission denied*.

I am able to open it through `sudo` but I would love to get this fixed as this is annoying me, that it wont work properly. I have been searching for the last two hours without finding a fix, so I was hoping anyone could give me a helping hand.

Comment: is you question solved?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to install the MySQL Startup Item.  Then you get a Preference pane for MySQL.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/macosx-installation-startupitem.html for full instructions.

---

Re your comment:

It's often required for services like mysql.server need to run as a uid other than your user login.  For instance, the MySQL data directory may only be writeable by the *mysql* uid.  So starting such a service must be done from a user that can change the uid of the process.  The root uid can do that, so it's necessary to use `sudo` to launch service processes like mysql.server.

---

TL;DR:

## **YOU HAVE TO USE SUDO.**

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I can use the Panel for starting the server alright, but i still dont get Permission to write commands in terminal.

Comment: Thanks again Bill, that answer is just a little too technical for me right now. Can you provide me with a way to fix my problem?

Comment: Worked like charm. Its 2024 and i had same issue, USE sudo mysql.server start

Answer (score -1):

If you a absolute newbie to MYSQL and you just want to use the MYSQL server to test your code on you local MAC I would advice you to take a look at [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html) / [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info). Xampp offers a complete out of the box install for everything you need for a development servers (Apache server, MySQL, PHP, etc).  Note, that I XAMPP / MAMP is not suitable for production server setting.

I personally use the XAMPP Windows version. I haven't tried MAMP but I have come across it many times . The XAMPP for Mac version seem not to have been update for a while so I suggest you give MAMP a try.

You could of course try to get your current install to work but that might require some work. Also with regard to firewall / security issues. With the out of the box version you will have to do a lot less. Why reinvent the wheel if you can easily install a out of the box version.